# How to prove that $m_{\delta'}^* \leq m_{\delta}^*$ for $0 < \delta < \delta' \leq +\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, $F$ a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ and $l:F \to [0, +\infty]$ be a non-negative set function on $F$. Suppose that 1.) for every $\delta > 0$ there exists a countable collection $S_i \in F, i \in \mathbb{N}: \Omega = \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}S_i$ and $\mathrm{diam}(S_i) \leq \delta$, 2.) for every $\delta > 0$ there exists $S \in F: l(S) \leq \delta$ and $\mathrm{diam}(S) \leq \delta$.

For $\delta > 0$ define $m_\delta^*(A) = \inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(S_i): S_i \in F, A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i, \mathrm{diam}(S_i) \leq \delta\}$. I'd like to argue in a rigorous way why $m_{\delta'}^*(A) \leq m_{\delta}^*(A), 0 < \delta < \delta' \leq \infty$.

At the moment I'm struggling with the algebraic manipulation of the inequalities and whatnot involving the definitions of $m_\delta^*$. Namely, let $(A_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(B_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be to covers for a set $A$ such that $\mathrm{diam}(A_i) \leq \delta, \mathrm{diam}(B_i) \leq \delta', i \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $\mathrm{diam}(A_i) \leq \mathrm{diam}(B_i) \leq \delta'$, and thus $m_{\delta'}^* \leq \min\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i), \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(B_i)\}\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i)$, and $m_{\delta}^* \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty l(A_i)$. But how do I progress from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your second condition, but I think your argument can be proven in a much easier way.

Denote by $\mathcal{F_\delta}$ the collection of sets $S$  in $F$ such that $\text{diam}(S)<\delta$. You can define the collection of sums

$$ \mathcal{S}_{\delta}(A):=\Big \{ \sum_{j=1}^\infty l(S_j):\;  S_j\in \mathcal{F}_\delta, A\subseteq \cup_{j=1}^\infty S_j \Big\}. $$

Using that notation $m_\delta^*(A)=\inf\mathcal{S}_\delta(A)$. You can also see that for $\delta'>\delta$, $\mathcal{F_\delta} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\delta'}$ and therefore $\mathcal{S}_{\delta}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{S}_{\delta'}(A)$. Then, by monotonicity of $\inf$ with resepect to set inclusion, you obtain immediately that $m^*_{\delta'}(A)\leq m^*_{\delta}(A)$.